# What employment can someone obtain if they were not given the PhD after studying and publishing?

Tags: phd, thesis, advisor, job-search, job

Suppose, after six years of study toward a PhD, my advisor refuses to give me PhD because he is not happy with my work.  (I am in India, currently in my third year of the PhD, studying computational biology, dealing with the computational aspects of host pathogen interactions, after doing my bachelors and masters degree in computer science.) After 6 years of work (assuming after 3 years if this situation remains same), if I have not gotten the degree, although I will have my publication record, with all first authorship.

**My question is , with 6 years of research experience and papers that I have worked on, with all first authorship, what types of jobs would I be able to apply for, without a PhD degree?**

My question is not about what is legal or illegal in PhD. My question is what is in bold...

A little info regarding my university: A student's fate depends on her advisor, higher authority cannot do anything...

**Edit** (from comment):

I am in my 3rd year of phd.

Comment: Don't be silly, your advisor doesn't own the university. If you indeed meet the university requirements, you can just talk to someone higher level.

Comment: @SmallChess That's not really how it works for Ph.D.'s.  For such a degree there is usually a dissertation committee which attends the thesis defense and collectively decides whether the student passes. It is this committee approval which forms part of the university requirements. The size of the committee varies depending on various factors.  Mine was three members, but I've seen five member committees.  A simple majority rules vote probably suffices. Though a "no" vote from the advisor would be unusual (they shouldn't let you defend if they don't think you'll pass).

Comment: @zibadawatimmy thats exactly my point, if my advisor does not let me defend my thesis, then what do i do?

Comment: @Rishika What evidence do you have to suggest that your advisor would be against you receiving the degree?  Have they told you you're not ready or something? This sounds like paranoia.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I am in my 3rd year of phd. I have one journal published, 1 journal communicated, one conference communicated, one paper about to be communicated to a journal, and he says that I have no work for thesis, but i know i have... It makes me think if this is his mentality now, which is very demotivating, what will happen in the future....

Comment: @Rishika How much one is expected to publish before a defense varies wildly between fields (and even subfields).  My Ph.D. was obtained with a single 40-page, single author paper.  I've known others to have hundreds of pages of published work to their name.  After three years, your amount of work may actually be below the typical standard for a defense in your area. Have you talked with your advisor about what it is you need to achieve and do, and what the game plan for getting that done is?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy he wants ground breaking work. pretty abstract term. He himself is not clear as to what he wants, yet he keeps saying, not enough...

Comment: I'm troubled by the comment 'higher authority cannot do anything...' -- are you sure? What university does not protect its students? At my university, students have all the power to change supervisor, and if they want to submit their thesis against their supervisor's advice , we have processes that bypasses a student's supervisor(s); this usually means appointing an independent, senior academic staff to take over the role of the supervisor.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus if i change my advisor now, my present advisor will become vindictive which will be bad fr my work.... Also, there are no written rules stating whether higher authority has the power or not...

Comment: Voting to close, as OP says she would like to know what types of jobs she can apply for without a PhD, but we don't even know what field she's been studying or what country she's in.

Comment: @aparente001 I have updated the question

Comment: Please clarify the inconsistency between _After 6 years of work_ and _I am in my 3rd year of phd_

Comment: Vote to close for at least two reasons (1) inconsistency between 6 years and 3rd year of PhD. (2) The question is too broad. There are **billions** of working people without PhD. No one can answer what type of jobs a non-PhD can apply.

Comment: I think the OP is at year 3, and is worrying about what happens if, in three years time, at the end of year 6, the advisor still does not consider the work sufficient for a PhD.

Comment: There is still an issue that it isn't really clear if you are looking for a non-academic job (which would not be on-topic here, so we can't really help you), or if you are looking for an academic job option you could have without being granted your PhD (effectively this would just be looking for academic jobs with a masters only - which I can say is a very limited option, unfortunately). Without a PhD, you generally need to seek jobs outside academia that have a fit with your skills and abilities, and that don't explicitly require the degree - aka, "industry".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations on the publications you have achieved thus far.

> If I change my advisor now, my present advisor will become vindictive. [...] A students fate depends on her advisor; higher authority cannot do anything.

It sounds like your best bet, if you want to stay where you are, would be to avoid conflict with your advisor.

> I am in my 3rd year of phd.

I don't know anyone who completed a PhD in two or even three years.

Comment: The PO stated that he has six years of research experience. I wonder if that also includes the time spent on the masters. If so getting a PhD in three years doesn't seem that outrageous.

Comment: My question is given in bold. Everyone seems to be talking out of topic... It not about what is right of wrong, it is about what job can i get with such experience and journal papers...

Comment: @Rishika - That is not a question we can answer.  We don't even know what field you have been studying or what country you're in.  Have you looked at some job descriptions?  Have you gone to see the office that helps students with their job search (if your university has one)?

Comment: @aparente001 I have made the necessary updation

Comment: @Rishika - Thanks for the additional info.  I hope you don't mind my asking -- but (a) why so impatient? (being in your third year, it seems rather presumptuous to be expecting to be graduating already); (b) *Have* you looked at some job descriptions, and does your university have an office that helps students find appropriate job openings?

Comment: @aparente001 no I am not impatient, I am just assuming the worse. If the worse happens after 3 years, what are my alternate choices.... That all that I want to know....

Comment: @Rishika - See if my rewrite feels true to what you want to ask.  Rollback if not.

Comment: @aparente001 perfect